# Unity IoC - resolve named dependency different path

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm not sure how to make a named dependency with unity to follow the different resolution path. So if I have

```
public interface IService
{
    SomeMethod();
}

public class Service : IService
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;
    public Service(IRepository repository)
    {
    this.repository = repository;
    }
    public SomeMethod 
    { 
        //some implementation here
    }
}
```

and underneath I have a Repository : IRepository, NHibernateContext : INHibernateContext,
ISession, etc.

My question is if I do next in my Global.asax:

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>("GlobalContext");
```

then how do I make it inject the NHibernateContext (or some other hierarchical dependency) within the "GlobalContext" path (not using the default registered type)?

Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a while I had a similar need on some other project, but was using Castle Windsor. The way I would do it now, taken I need a different dependency resolution in some application path, I would use a child container.

1. Create a child container and register dependencies having different resolution
2. Register child container itself with as a named instance.
3. In the entry point (in my case controller factory) check whether need to resolve via parent container or child. If needed resolve child container and resolve hierarchy chain using it. If no registration in child container exists it would use parent dependency resolver.

Answer (score 2):

When using named registrations like this, you can't rely on auto-wiring anymore, so you need to be more specific with your registration. So assuming you have these:

```
container.RegisterType<INHibernateContext, NHibernateContext>("GlobalContext");
container.RegisterType<ISession, NHibernateSession>("GlobalContext");
```

And when you resolve IRepository, "GlobalContext" you want those specific dependencies injected. Assuming you've got a constructor that takes those two parameters, you explicitly tell the container which name you want to use:

```
container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>("GlobalContext",
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<INHibernateContext>("GlobalContext"),
        new ResolvedParameter<ISession>("GlobalContext")
    )
);
```

This tells the container to use the constructor that takes INHibernateContext and ISession, to resolve those parameters through the container, and use the GlobalContext name when resolving them.

Similarly, to wire up your service:

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>("GlobalContext",
    new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("GlobalContext")
);
```

And the final resolve call:

```
container.Resolve<IService>("GlobalContext");
```

should build your object graph the way you want.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I was hoping I would not need to go through the whole injection hierarchy by setting each InjectionConstructor separately (I have 4 injection levels atm, but just imagine what would it be in a more complicated scenario).

Comment: Perhaps something in the new Unity 3.0 registration-by-convention stuff might help? I haven't used it yet, so I can't say for sure.